# Regular expression for matching SQL spatial data

Tags: sql, regex, spatial

how to create a regular expression for matching MySQL spatial multiline string coordinates.
for matching:

```
(33 44, 98 33)
(10 10, 20 20), (15 15, 30 15)
(10 10, 20 20), (15 15, 30 15), (10 10, 11 11, 22 22)
```

Comment: Have you tried?  Where are you going to be using the regex? MySQL query, after retrieving results, ... somewhere else?  If you haven't tried and want a coder to solve it for you, that's why we get hired... people who can't do it, ask us to.  SO is for when you try and need a little help.

Comment: I need validate string before insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To match every single coordinates :

```
(\((?:\d+\s\d+,\s)*\d+\s\d+\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
/(
  \(         # opening parenthesis  "("
    (?:      # non-capturing group  "("
      \d+    # one or more number   "(33"
      \s     # a space              "(33 "
      \d+    # one or more number   "(33 44"
      ,\s    # a comma and a space  "(33 44, "
    )*       # repeat n time        "(33 44, "
    \d+\s\d+ # plus a last one      "(33 44, 98 33"
  \)         # closing parenthesis  "(33 44, 98 33)"
)/x
```

### To match every coordinates group (= every line) :

```
((?:\((?:\d+\s\d+,\s)*\d+\s\d+\),\s)*\((?:\d+\s\d+,\s)*\d+\s\d+\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
/(
  (?:                            # non-capturing group ""
    \((?:\d+\s\d+,\s)*\d+\s\d+\) # cf first regex      "(10 10, 20 20)"
    ,\s                          # comma and space     "(10 10, 20 20), "
  )*                             # repeat n time       "(10 10, 20 20), (15 15, 30 15), "
  \((?:\d+\s\d+,\s)*\d+\s\d+\)   # plus a last one     "(10 10, 20 20), (15 15, 30 15), (10 10, 11 11, 22 22)"
)/x
```